# My proof that if for a k degree polynomial $P(x)$, for the matrix $A$, $P(A)=0$ then $A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, polynomials, inverse

Let $P(x)$ be a $k$-degree polynomial with with non-zero free coefficient. Prove that if for matrix $A$, $P(A)$=0, then $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}$ is $k-1$ degree $A$ polynomial.

Here's my proof, I would like to know if that's ok:

Let $P(x)$ be defined: $P(x)=a_1x+a_2x^2+ \dots +a_kx^k+a_{k+1}$. We know $P(A)=0$, so that:

$$P(A)=a_1A+a_2A^2+\dots +a_kA^k+a_{k+1}=0$$  $$A(a_1+a_2A+ \dots +a_kA^{k-1})=-a_{k+1}$$

$-a_{k+1}I=-a_{k+1}$, so:

$$A(a_1+a_2A+ \dots +a_kA^{k-1})=-a_{k+1}I$$
$$A{(a_1+a_2A+ \dots+a_kA^{k-1})\over -a_{k+1}}=I.$$

Lets define: $A^{-1}={(a_1+a_2A+\dots +a_kA^{k-1})\over -a_{k+1}}$, and then we found that $AA^{-1}=I$. Thus $A$ is invertible, and we can see $A^{-1}$ is a $k-1$ degree polynomial. QED

Is this proof valid? Thanks in advance. [Translated from another language]

Comment: What do you mean "with free coefficient"? Did you mean "with non-zero free coefficient"=עם מקדם חופשי שונה מאפס?

Comment: Exactly =] Thanks.

Comment: If *free coefficient* means that the constant term is non-zero, then this is ok. Mind you, that's most likely is exactly what it means, for otherwise the conclusion may not hold...

Comment: It looks fine, but it should be:  " $\,A^{-1}\,$ is a polynomial in $\,A\,$ of degree $\,k-1\,$ " ...nice. +1 for showing your own work.

Comment: It is quite unusual to call the constant coefficient $c_{k+1}$, since it is the coefficient of $x^0=1$, it would be natural to call it $c_0$. As you wrote down $P(x)$ it looks at first glance as if there is no constant term, contrary to the hypothesis. Not really an error, by quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

*This CW answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As already noted in the comments: Your proof is correct. Thanks for showing your own work.

Comment: (Well, it is not that we *defined* $A^{-1}=blah$, as the solution claims. Rather, we verified that $A^{-1}=blah$.)